# Changing Specific Rows to Columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Everyone first of all the question title proposed that We need to change some of the rows to columns in SQL.

The Table which I have is a Wide Table Having 203 Columns and **73 Rows in Total**

Below is the Format of the Table:

```
| R1C1  | R1C2 | R1C3 |.................. C203 |
|-------|------|------|------------------------|
| R2C1  | R2C2 | R2C3 |                        |
| R3C1  | R3C2 | R3C3 |                        |
...........................................
| R73C1 | R73C2|R73C3 |                        |
```

Hopefully this will give the idea of having a table of 73 x 203. Now what need to be done is that I need to change From **R1C1 to R18C1** to Columns that will be our first **18 Columns**.

Now Moving Towards Next **R1C2 to R18C2** and changing it to Columns That will start from the 19th Column.

and so on.

The Final Table will have 4 Rows and 3654 Columns (18 x 203).

How can I achieve this.

A Good Suggestion might be **PIVOTS**, but the Problem is using a Loop with Pivot and I am not good enough with SQL.

Now, What I have done so far is,

```
    BULK
    INSERT CSVTest
    FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
    WITH
    (
     FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    )
```

Can Anyone help me in this. Appreciated.

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff I actually mentioned above that the Table which is selected after the query is going to be Wide SQL Table.

Comment: "The Final Table will have 4 Rows and 3654 Columns (18 x 203)" - ummmm... what will you do then? Can you describe your end-goal, there has to be a better way than trying to deal with a table with 3.5k(!!) columns!

Comment: @sasfrog Actually, my end goal is as mentioned above is to get a Table with 4 x 3672 Columns.

Comment: Yeah @UmAir_Xajid but what are you planning to do with that colossally wide table? What's your business requirement?